# Implement reading from stream via copy

Tags: c++, io, istream, istream-iterator

I have a class which represents a character sequence and I’d like to implement an `operator >>` for it. My implementation currently looks like this:

```
inline std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, seq& rhs) {
    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(rhs));
    // `copy` doesn't know when to stop reading so it always also sets `fail`
    // along with `eof`, even if reading succeeded. On the other hand, when
    // reading actually failed, `eof` is not going to be set.
    if (in.fail() and in.eof())
        in.clear(std::ios_base::eofbit);
    return in;
}
```

However, the following predictably fails:

```
std::istringstream istr("GATTACA FOO");
seq s;
assert((istr >> s) and s == "GATTACA");
```

In particular, once we reach the space in “`GATTACA FOO`”, the copying stop (expected) and sets the failbit on the `istream` (also expected). However, the read operation actually succeeded as far as `seq` is concerned.

Can I model this at all using `std::copy`? I also thought of using an `istreambuf_iterator` instead but this doesn’t actually solve this particular problem.

What’s more, a read operation on the input “`GATTACAFOO`” *should fail* since that input doesn’t represent a valid DNA sequence (which is what my class represents). On the other hand, reading an `int` from the input `42foo` actually *succeeds* in C++ so maybe I should consider every valid prefix as a valid input?

(Incidentally, this would be fairly straightforward with an explicit loop but I’m trying to avoid explicit loops in favour of algorithms.)

Comment: If it's more straightforward with a loop than with algorithms (because you wouldn't be asking this otherwise), then just use a damn loop. Maintainability.

Comment: @Cat I didn’t say “more straightforward”. In fact, I claim that when using the *appropriate* algorithm (and if appropriate sequence adaptors exist) the algorithm solution is *always* more straightforward than using a loop.

Comment: You could use templates, and you could somehow find a way to use multiple inheritance, threads and anything you can dream of, but it just would make your life so much harder and not give you any visible benefits. So why force yourself to use iterators and algorithms that obviously don't fit the needs of the task at hand? Keep it simple, use that plain loop and go on to solve the real problems. Don't mess up your project with 15 lines of workarounds to get in one line of a library solution meant to be slick and elegant.

Comment: @Arne Whoa, take the chill pill, man. I’m not doing any of the things you’re accusing me of. And I’m explicitly asking *whether* my approach is at all appropriate. But if you dismiss this approach as “obviously [not] fit” then I think you cannot contribute much. Otherwise why do input iterator adaptors exist in the first place?

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry if I overstated that one. What I mean is: if you have to struggle to get the sequence adaptors then the algorithm is *not* more straightforward. In your case, you'll have to parse the input to validate it. Parsing does not fit with plain iterating algorithms, so I doubt you'll find anything suitable in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph as traps, obviously! ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not saying you said "more straightforward", I'm implying that it's more straightforward because you know how to do it with a loop but don't know how to do it with algorithms.

Comment: @Arne The problem here is that the C++ IO interface is generally f’ed up. Maybe a handful of people on the planet really understand it. Using iterators potentially confound the issue but take note that I don’t even know how to implement the input semantics correctly without using iterators (second to last paragraph).

Comment: I think the problem is that the istream is a one-pass sequence, but for all std:: algorithms you have to provide a proper end iterator that you don't have. The one-pass seuqence makes it impossible to first find that iterator and then copy. A `copy_while` algorithm would be needed here.

Comment: @ArneMertz, great minds think alike, see my answer for `copy_while` :) The problem is not due to the iostream interface, it's failing to grok that reading must stop before EOF and the code above always consumes all input. That's not the iostream interface's fault.

Comment: @Jonathan “The problem is not due to the iostream interface” – I beg to differ. I agree with your `copy_while` assessment (see my deleted answer) but I maintain that the problem *is* due to iostream’s interface. How many people are there *in the world* who really grok iostreams? Five? Less? Yeah, that’s a problem.

Comment: So how would you make it work with `fread` if you read until EOF?  It's completely wrong to consume the entire input, irrespective of the API.  Don't confuse "I don't understand it" with "noone understands it" ... it's obviously more than five.

Comment: @Jonathan The fact that iostreams are only really understood by a handful people is a quite widely believed fact. Most C++ experts who claim proficiency in other areas of the language are only too happy admit that they don’t understand iostreams (or locales; but well, the latter don’t work on all platforms anyway, e.g. OS X). Regarding the issue with EOF, I *do* know in principle how it’s supposed to work. But writing iostream operations which are consistent with the standard library is *hard*. Exhibit A: your answer is inconsistent with the behaviour of `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to `clear(eofbit)` because the `failbit` should stay set if reading failed due to reaching EOF. Otherwise if you just leave `eofbit` set without `failbit` then a loop such as `while (in >> s)` will attempt another read after reaching EOF, and then *that* read will set `failbit` again. Except if it was using your `operator>>` it would clear it, and try to read again. And again. And again. The right behaviour for a stream is to set `failbit` if reading failed because of EOF, so just leave it set.

To do this with iterators and an algorithm you'd need something like

```
copy_while(InputIter, InputIter, OutputIter, Pred);
```

which would copy the input sequence only while the predicate was true, but that doesn't exist in the standard library.  You could certainly write one though.

```
template<typename InputIter, typename OutputIter, typename Pred>
  OutputIter
  copy_while(InputIter begin, InputIter end, OutputIter result, Pred pred)
  {
    while (begin != end)
    {
      typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::value_type value = *begin;
      if (!pred(value))
        break;
      *result = value;
      result++;
      begin++;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Now you could use that like this:

```
inline bool
is_valid_seq_char(char c)
{ return std::string("ACGT").find(c) != std::string::npos; }

inline std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& in, seq& rhs)
{
    copy_while(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(rhs),
        &is_valid_seq_char);
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream istr("GATTACA FOO");
    seq s;
    assert((istr >> s) and s == "GATTACA");
}
```

This works, but the problem is that `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>` to read characters, so it skips over whitespace. This means the space following `"GATTACA"` is consumed by the algorithm and discarded, so adding this to the end of `main` would fail:

```
assert(istr.get() == ' ');
```

To solve this use `istreambuf_iterator` which doesn't skip whitespace:

```
inline std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& in, seq& rhs)
{
    copy_while(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(rhs),
        &is_valid_seq_char);
    return in;
}
```

To complete this, you probably want to indicate failure to extract a `seq` if no characters where extracted:

```
inline std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& in, seq& rhs)
{
    copy_while( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {},
        std::back_inserter(rhs), &is_valid_seq_char);
    if (seq.empty())
      in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);  // no seq in stream
    return in;
}
```

That final version also uses one of my favourite C++11 tricks to simpify it slightly, by using `{}` for the end iterator. The type of the second argument to `copy_while` must be the same as the type of the first argument, which is deduced as `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`, so the `{}` simply value-initializes another iterator of that same type.

**Edit:** If you want a closer match to `std::string` extraction then you can do so too:

```
inline std::istream&
operator>>(std::istream& in, seq& rhs)
{
    std::istream::sentry s(in);
    if (s)
    {
        copy_while( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), {},
                    std::back_inserter(rhs), &is_valid_seq_char);
        int eof = std::char_traits<char>::eof();
        if (std::char_traits<char>::eq_int_type(in.rdbuf()->sgetc(), eof))
            in.setstate(std::ios::eofbit);
    }
    if (rhs.empty())
        in.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return in;
}
```

The sentry will skip leading whitespace and if you reach the end of the input it will set `eofbit`.  The other change that should probably be made is to empty the `seq` before pushing anything into it, e.g. start with `rhs.clear()` or equivalent for your `seq` type.

Comment: I was originally going to mention in the question that I cannot use `istreambuf_iterator` since I’m not actually reading the stream’s underlying char type, I’m reading a custom type (which corresponds to a single `unsigned char`) and I need to use the that type’s stream input operator. I though of solving the problem using `noskipws` but I’ve given up for the moment.

Comment: Great, `copy_while` was just what I was thinking about in my comment. +1 for the `{}` trick, too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph why not reading from an iterator sequence that reads char and output to a iterator that writes your type? If there's an implicit conversion that should work.

Comment: @Arne There is no implicit conversion, and the explicit conversion will *throw* if the value is invalid, rather than putting the stream into an error state. But actually the latter isn’t a problem at all once I switch to using `take_while`, and the conversion issue I can work around. Thanks for the hint, I’ll try that.

Comment: Actually, this code doesn’t work entirely for me. In your example, `std::cin.eof() == false` after reading. If, on the other hand, I were reading a `std::string`, `eof` would be `true`. [Illustrative code](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cbdea16ce97fe0f0ecb318d71a84edb1)

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to get the same whitespace-skipping and `eofbit` behaviour as the extraction operator for `std::string`

Comment: @Jonathan Awesome. I’ve now actually taken the time to read the c++stdlib implementation of the stream input operator for `std::basic_string` as well (without your answer I wouldn’t have understood it). I hope now everything is settled, my code certainly seems to work, I’ve expanded the test cases to capture corner cases, and so far the behaviour seems exactly equivalent to `std::string`, with the (desired!) exception that `std::istringstream istr("ACG42"); seq s; int i{}; istr >> s >> i; assert(i == 42);`

Comment: Excellent :)  N.B. the verbose `std::char_traits` code in the final version is needed for the general `std::basic_istream` case, but for `std::istream` the check can be simplified to `in.rdbuf()->sgetc() == EOF` which is exactly equivalent for the `char_traits<char>` specialization

Answer (score 2):

> In particular, once we reach the space in “GATTACA FOO”, the copying
>   stop (expected)

That assumption is already false. Instead you't get

```
std::istringstream istr("GATTACA FOO");
seq s;
assert(!(istr >> s) && s == "GATTACAFOO");
```

Copying using an `istream_iterator<char>` and a standard `copy`algorithm can't work, because that will always extract character until the end of stream.

You need a copy that terminates prematurely, if an end condition is reached and the end condition must not extract the non-matching character (i.e. using `in.peek()` or even directly looking at the streambuf).

To do so using `std::copy()` would require your own special purpose stream iterator (that compares equal to an end iterator, if the termination condition is matched by the next character. IMHO that creates more obscurity than an explicit loop. YMMV

Comment: Right, don't consume the entire input then bugger about with stream state flags, consume a valid sequence (which means checking as you go and stopping at the end of the valid sequence, like the `"42foo"` case, when in doubt, do as the ints do!) and only manually alter the stream state if you fail to extract any valid sequence (because calling the `operator>>` overload for extracting sequences when there's no sequence in the stream is a failure.) Let the stream manage `eofbit` when it reaches EOF, don't set it earlier and don't clear it if EOF is reached